# How to prove that an algorithm has no deadlock

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, concurrency, synchronization, deadlocks

I need to mathematically prove that this algorithm is deadlock-free:

```
semaphore semA = 1;
semaphore semB = 3;

process P {
    while (true) {
        P(semA);
        <print “TA”>;
        V(semB);
    }
}

process Q {
    while (true) {
        P(semB);
        P(semB);
        P(semB);
        P(semB);
        <print “RA”>;
        V(semA);
        V(semA);
        V(semA);
        V(semA);
    }
}
```

This program prints a sequence of "TA" and "RA" according to its synchronization rules. I know how to prove its correctness starting from the invariant $-3 \le n\mathrm{TA} - 4n\mathrm{RA} \le 1$ but I don't how to start to prove that is deadlock-free. Do I need to count the number of P(semA)/P(semB)?